# How to paint fully transparent pixels/points in P2D mode?

Tags: java, transparency, processing

According to the [Processing Reference](http://processing.org/reference/stroke_.html), `stroke(gray, alpha)` allows to set the color and opacity of the stroke. With the default color mode, an alpha value of 255 denotes full opacity, while a value of 0 should correspond to complete transparency. While this works with the (default) JAVA2D renderer, I can't seem to paint fully transparent points in P2D mode.

This code clearly renders a pixel at the center of the canvas, even though the alpha value is set to 0 (fully transparent):

```
public class Transparency extends PApplet {

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        size(200, 200, P2D);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        stroke(0, 0);
        point(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { Transparency.class.getSimpleName() });
    }
```

}

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a processing bug.
For now the only thing you can do is check the transparency yourself, and don't draw if it's zero

Comment: I try to approach problems based on the "SELECT is not broken" idiom (http://bit.ly/U5c5L) but I will happily accept your answer if you can  provide a Bug ID or a link to any other official reference -- TIA!